# Account ID from Authorization Code Grant is different than from Legacy Header

Tags: docusignapi

We're moving from Legacy Header to Authorization Code Grant. Previously, we were getting an Account ID by calling `AuthenticationAPI.login()` method, with the `X-DocuSign-Authentication` header, and the callback provides a `loginInfo` argument with `email`, `accounts`, etc.

Now since we've moved to OAuth2, (using [passport-docusign](https://github.com/docusign/passport-docusign/)), in the callback `function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {}`, the `profile` looks identical to the previous `loginInfo`, except the `AccountId`.  The previous one had about 8 digits, but the one I'm getting now looks like `xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`.

I tried using that one with the rest of the calls we have, however I get the error `USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

With legacy you used to get friendlyaccountid or external accountid which is of 8 digits. Now with account server’s oauth you are getting accountguid which is a guid representation of your account in DS datacenter. Ideally you should base uri returned in /userinfo api call and accountguid to make further non-account server related calls. The user credentials which you were using earlier in legacy auth header should now give you consent to generate access token and with accesstoken you can make the Api calls without any issues.